# 3D Bin packing and Intersection locations

Tags: python, bin-packing

I am currently using Py3dbp to show how I could fill a shipping container with parts.  I have modified it a good bit but I need to add a "shelf" to place items on inside the bin. Here is what it looks like so far:
[image: Container with Shelf and Door]

Here the red line is the door of the container and the blue is the shelf.  As you can see the shelf is drawn in the figure but the items ignore the area.  I need to have the items pack around the shelf.  There is an auxiliary method script in the py3dbp library that has an intersection function:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from .constants import Axis


def rectIntersect(item1, item2, x, y):
    d1 = item1.getDimension()
    d2 = item2.getDimension()

    cx1 = item1.position[x] + d1[x]/2
    cy1 = item1.position[y] + d1[y]/2
    cx2 = item2.position[x] + d2[x]/2
    cy2 = item2.position[y] + d2[y]/2

    ix = max(cx1, cx2) - min(cx1, cx2)
    iy = max(cy1, cy2) - min(cy1, cy2)

    return ix < (d1[x]+d2[x])/2 and iy < (d1[y]+d2[y])/2


def intersect(item1, item2):
    return (
        rectIntersect(item1, item2, Axis.WIDTH, Axis.HEIGHT) and
        rectIntersect(item1, item2, Axis.HEIGHT, Axis.DEPTH) and
        rectIntersect(item1, item2, Axis.WIDTH, Axis.DEPTH)
    )

    
def binIntersect(item, bin, x, y):
    # Assuming 'bin' has 'width', 'height', 'depth', and 'position' attributes
    d1 = item.getDimension()
    d2 = [bin.width, bin.height, bin.depth/2]  # Modify based on your Bin class attributes

    cx1 = item.position[x] + d1[x]/2
    cy1 = item.position[y] + d1[y]/2
    cx2 = bin.width + d2[Axis.WIDTH]/2
    cy2 = bin.height + d2[Axis.HEIGHT]/2

    ix = max(cx1, cx2) - min(cx1, cx2)
    iy = max(cy1, cy2) - min(cy1, cy2)

    return ix < (d1[Axis.WIDTH] + d2[Axis.WIDTH])/2 and iy < (d1[Axis.HEIGHT] + d2[Axis.HEIGHT])/2


def itemIntersectsWithBin(item, bin):
    # Assuming 'item' has 'position' and 'getDimension' methods
    return (
        binIntersect(item, bin, Axis.WIDTH, Axis.HEIGHT) and
        binIntersect(item, bin, Axis.HEIGHT, Axis.DEPTH) and
        binIntersect(item, bin, Axis.WIDTH, Axis.DEPTH/2)
    )


def getLimitNumberOfDecimals(number_of_decimals):
    return Decimal('1.{}'.format('0' * number_of_decimals))


def set2Decimal(value, number_of_decimals=0):
    number_of_decimals = getLimitNumberOfDecimals(number_of_decimals)

    return Decimal(value).quantize(number_of_decimals)
```

I added the binIntersect and itemIntersectWithBin functions to try to solve this issue I am having, but it does not seem to work when I add use it in the main script PackItem function here:

```
def putItem(self, item, pivot,axis=None):
        ''' put item in bin '''
        fit = False
        valid_item_position = item.position
        item.position = pivot
        shelf = self.shelfBin()
        
        # rotate = RotationType.ALL if item.updown == True else RotationType.Notupdown
        rotate = RotationType.ALL if item.updown else RotationType.Notupdown
        for i in range(0, len(rotate)):
            item.rotation_type = i
            dimension = item.getDimension()
            shelf_dimension = shelf.getBinDimension()
            # rotatate
  
            if (
                self.width < pivot[0] + dimension[0] or
                self.height < pivot[1] + dimension[1] or
                self.depth < pivot[2] + dimension[2]
            ):
                continue

            fit = True

            # Check for intersection with shelf_bin
            for current_item_in_bin in self.items:
                if intersect(current_item_in_bin, item) or itemIntersectsWithBin(current_item_in_bin, shelf):
                    fit = False
                    break

            # shelf.dimension = (self.width, self.height, self.depth / 2 + 6)  # Adjust dimensions based on your shelf Bin definition
            # if itemIntersectsWithBin(item, shelf):
            #     fit = False
            #     break

            if fit:
                # cal total weight
                if self.getTotalWeight() + item.weight > self.max_weight:
                    print("Too Heavy for container: ", self.item.partno)
                    fit = False
                    return fit
                
                # fix point float prob
                if self.fix_point == True :
                        
                    [w,h,d] = dimension
                    [x,y,z] = [float(pivot[0]),float(pivot[1]),float(pivot[2])]

                    for i in range(3):
                        # fix height
                        y = self.checkHeight([x,x+float(w),y,y+float(h),z,z+float(d)])
                        # fix width
                        x = self.checkWidth([x,x+float(w),y,y+float(h),z,z+float(d)])
                        # fix depth
                        z = self.checkDepth([x,x+float(w),y,y+float(h),z,z+float(d)])

                    # check stability on item 
                    # rule : 
                    # 1. Define a support ratio, if the ratio below the support surface does not exceed this ratio, compare the second rule.
                    # 2. If there is no support under any vertices of the bottom of the item, then fit = False.
                    if self.check_stable == True :
                        # Cal the surface area of ​​item.
                        # item_area_lower = int(dimension[0] * dimension[1])
                        item_area_lower = dimension[0] * dimension[1]
                        # Cal the surface area of ​​the underlying support.
                        support_area_upper = 0
                        for i in self.fit_items:
                            # Verify that the lower support surface area is greater than the upper support surface area * support_surface_ratio.
                            if z == i[5]  :
                                area = len(set([ j for j in range(int(x),int(x+int(w)))]) & set([ j for j in range(int(i[0]),int(i[1]))])) * \
                                len(set([ j for j in range(int(y),int(y+int(h)))]) & set([ j for j in range(int(i[2]),int(i[3]))]))
                                support_area_upper += area

                        # If not , get four vertices of the bottom of the item.
                        if support_area_upper / item_area_lower < self.support_surface_ratio :
                            four_vertices = [[x,y],[x+float(w),y],[x,y+float(h)],[x+float(w),y+float(h)]]
                            #  If any vertices is not supported, fit = False.
                            c = [False,False,False,False]
                            for i in self.fit_items:
                                if z == i[5] :
                                    for jdx,j in enumerate(four_vertices) :
                                        if (i[0] <= j[0] <= i[1]) and (i[2] <= j[1] <= i[3]) :
                                            c[jdx] = True
                            if False in c :
                                item.position = valid_item_position
                                fit = False
                                return fit
                        
                    self.fit_items = np.append(self.fit_items,np.array([[x,x+float(w),y,y+float(h),z,z+float(d)]]),axis=0)
                    item.position = [set2Decimal(x),set2Decimal(y),set2Decimal(z)]

                    # shelf.putItem(copy.deepcopy(item))
                    self.items.append(copy.deepcopy(item))


                # if fit :
                # #     # if shelf_bin and not shelf_bin.is_stable():
 

                #     self.items.append(copy.deepcopy(item))
            else :
                item.position = valid_item_position

            return fit

        else :
            item.position = valid_item_position

        return fit
```

So the end goal is to have the capability to read the area of the shelf and check to see the item intersects the area of the shelf and if it does, to try and add it on top the shelf or remove it.

For reference, here is the visual for the shelf.

```
self._shelf(ax,0, 0, float(self.depth)/2-0.5, float(self.width), float(self.height), 6.0,color='blue',mode=1,linewidth=2,text="Shelf")
        # fit rotation type
```